# Use csv file to populate class data, then add node to a vector

Tags: c++, csv, class, vector

I have a class called `Node`. `Node` requires 4 pieces of data, `name`, `referenceNumber`, `latitude` and `longitude.

I wish to populate these data values with the data stored in a csv file.

Once the `Nodes` data is set it will be stored in a vector array

I was thinking of doing this by reading the file 1 line at a time to a string and then splitting the string at the commas to a array then using the array to populate the class values. I would then push the node in to the vector array.

The desired result would be able to search the vector for a certain node and then view the nodes info

EDIT

```cpp
vector<Node*> mPlaces;
    string line, refHolder, latHolder, longHolder;
    ifstream finPlaces("Places");
    if (finPlaces.is_open)
    {
        while (getline(finPlaces, line))
        {
            stringstream ss(line);
            getline(ss, mName, ',');
            getline(ss, refHolder, ',');
            getline(ss, latHolder, ',');
            getline(ss, longHolder, ',');

            mReferenceNumber = stoi(refHolder);
            mLatitude = stof(latHolder);
            mLongitude = stof(longHolder);


        }


        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

This is what I came up with in the end.

I am still struggling with how to add the `node` to my `vector` any tips on how to do this?

Comment: The standard idiom would be for a node to know how to read itself from a comma separated stream. But otherwise the plan above is good.